# Calculating total working hours based on shifts

Tags: postgresql

I would like to calculate how many hours each employee has worked for a certain time period, based on information from this table:

```
       start              employee_id

2014-08-10 18:10:00             5  
2014-08-10 13:30:00             7  
2014-08-10 09:00:00             7  
2014-08-09 23:55:00             4  
2014-08-09 16:23:00             12  
2014-08-09 03:59:00             9  
2014-08-08 20:05:00             7  
2014-08-08 13:00:00             8
```

Each employee replaces another employee and that's where his work is done, so there are no empty slots.

The desired format of the result would be the following:

```
employee_id         total_minutes_worked
```

I'm trying to think of the best way to achieve this, so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: is there any field to indicate when employees finished work?

Comment: hi, yes, each employee is replaced by another one, so his shift ends at the start time of the next

Comment: Is it postgresql, mysql or both?

Comment: *the end time of the first employee is the same as the start time of the next employee* is not a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the total time as:

```
select employee_id, sum(stop - start) 
from (
    select start, lead(start) over (order by start) as stop, employee_id
    from t
) as x 
group by employee_id;
```

It remains to format the time, but I assume this it not what puzzles you

Comment: thank you, it works! for formatting the time to hours, extract(epoch from sum(stop - start))/3600 as total

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'GroupBy' clause to first create a group of the same employee id

than you should calculate the time by checking the start time of work and end time of work in each slot.

(NOTE - you should maintain the start time and end time both of the employee in each slot of there shift)

Comment: Ok I posted my answer prior to your latest comment that the end time of the first employee is the same as the start time of the next employee